# Show reason for closure when reviewing questions for reopening

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closing-questions, review

It would be helpful if the reopen review queue always explained why the questions were initially closed.  When reviewing close votes, the system shows the reasons other reviewers gave for closing the question, like this:
[image]

In the re-open queue, however, the header sometimes just looks like this:
[image]

I suggest that the two messages should be combined, into something like this.

> This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?
>
> It was initially flagged because:
>
> - Reason #1
> - Reason #2

Obviously, one can click through to the question's page to see the closure reason, but it would be convenient to have this information on the page already, as is done during the initial closure. This information is not provided by the (more) link, which just explains what each button does.

Comment: This is an issue we've remarked on here before, but I don't recall if it had its own thread or arose in the discussion of other matters. You're asked to make a decision but the information you need isn't there, you have to go looking, and the whole thing is clunky. At least if the reason was visible it would sometimes save further clicking ("unclear? looks clear enough now")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, originally when this queue was created it was only a queue for questions that received reopen votes. It only ever had the "Question" tab which already displays a banner which lists the reason it was closed. We didn't put this information into the top information box because all it would be doing is duplicating information.

Now that revisions bump questions into this queue and you most often do *not* end up on a screen which displays this information, we've gone ahead and added it into the top as well so that it is easy to access. Note that it will only display the top-level reason for the closure. It does not display all the reasons that were selected by various close votes and does not display off-topic sub-reasons.

Comment: When you go to the reopen queue, you initially land on the `revision` tab. What might be best & easiest would be to just initially land on the `question (revised)` tab instead.